# $.ajax callback using model with spaces in values

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, model-view-controller, urlencode

I have this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/Controller/method?A=@Model.A&B=@Model.B&C=@Model.C&D=@Model.D',
         dataType: 'html',
         cache: false,
         success: function (res) {
         target.html(res);
         setup();
     }
});
```

The problem I think I am having is that @Model.C has spaces in the value.

Is there a setting that will put the %20 in automatically, or another way things are usually done

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be going to that url when debugging

Comment: If you look at the network tab of the browser dev tools, or add and Error function to the call you are seeing a 404? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **encodeURI**

```js
console.log(encodeURI("a b c"))
```

and that will encode other characters as well. Just make sure you do not call it on the whole URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Model.C.Replace(" ", "%20")`, if spaces are the only extraneous characters you expect to find. You can find a more detailed information from the RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1